# NotSerializableException when doing file I/O using static method

Tags: java, static, io, notserializableexception

So, I've got two classes that I've declared static (by making their methods static and their constructors private), Synchronizer and UserProfile. Synchronizer's saveData() function calls UserProfile's saveData() function:

```
private static void saveData(){
    UserProfile.saveData(data, dataFile);
}
```

Here is UserProfile.saveData(...):

```
public static void saveData(Object obj, File file){
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Synchronizer and UserProfile both implement Serializable and have an autogenerated serialVersionUID.

Any help? I'm pretty sure I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Edit: Here is the output.

```
    Restoring sync data
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jsoup.nodes.Document
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:733)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at UserProfile.restoreData(UserProfile.java:93)
    at Synchronizer.restoreData(Synchronizer.java:74)
    at Processor.<init>(Processor.java:8)
    at CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:15)
    at TuneSnatch.main(TuneSnatch.java:5)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jsoup.nodes.Document
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at UserProfile.saveData(UserProfile.java:80)
    at Synchronizer.saveData(Synchronizer.java:87)
    at Synchronizer.addHTML(Synchronizer.java:44)
    at Processor.sync(Processor.java:100)
    at CommandLine.launch(CommandLine.java:99)
    at TuneSnatch.main(TuneSnatch.java:6)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: It means "data", whatever class it really is, isn't serializable.

Comment: should be `org.jsoup.nodes.Document` (in an `ArrayList`) that is not serializable. The object that you want to serialize needs to support it, not the code that initiates serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Object `obj` in this line

```
oos.writeObject(obj);
```

Appears to be the issue, not your `UserProfile` or `Synchronizable` classes. I think it's not serializable. Judging from your exception message I guess it's of type `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`, which does not implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

What must be serializable is not the class you use to serialize objects, but the serialized objects themselves. In this case, the object referenced by `data` (of type `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`) must be serializable, because it's the state of this object which is serialized and stored in a file.

Making your utility classes serializable doesn't make sense: you never create instances of them, and thus never serialize these non-existing instances.

To make an analogy, when you want to send a letter, you paste a stamp on the letter, because that's what is sent. Your code tries to send a letter by pasting a stamp on the postman.

Comment: +1 for the interesting pictures your analogy conjures up.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The `NotSerializableException` is being thrown because some of the data you are attempting to save (the `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`) does not implement Serializable.

Make sure your data object implements Serializable and your error will go away.  In this case, that may not be possible since the object comes from a 3rd party library, so you may want to see if the object can be converted to another format for serialization (the Document may have an export or conversion method of some sort).

You may be able to simply call `Document.toString()` to get a serialiazable string representation of the document, assuming that it generates a lossless and suitably parseable string that can be read by `Jsoup.parse(String)`.

E.g.

```
public static void saveData(Document document, File file)
{
    String html = document.toString();
    ...
    oos.writeObject(html);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense that the classes being used to do the serializing are serializable. It is the object that you are saving to the file that must implement serializable. You are not trying to save your utility classes, you are just using them to implement the serializing of the object you are trying to persist.